# PyCharm with Docker image returns "Process finished with exit code 128" on RUN command

Tags: docker, pycharm

I'm trying to complete [this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/12/using-docker-in-pycharm/#comment-295413) very basic tutorial. It's a short explenation of how to run Docker image as remote interpreter in PyCharm.
I'm using Win7 and latest PyCharm version.
First I had problems with the paths but after playing with them for a bit now they looks like this:

- Environment variables: *DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE(djangotestone.settings)
  & PYTHONUNBUFFERED(1)*
- Working Directory:
  *\C\Users\Passanova\PycharmProjects\djangotestone\djangotestone*
- Path Mappings:
  */C/Users/Passanova/PycharmProjects/djangotestone=/opt/project*
- Docker container settings: *-v
  /C/Users/Passanova/PycharmProjects/djangotestone:/opt/project*

So now when I atempt RUN comannd I get the following return:

```
1f52b930ec0f:python -u C:/Users/Passanova/PycharmProjects/djangotestone/manage.py runserver 8000

Process finished with exit code 128
```

The server does not start and I'm not able to verify the container by `docker ps -l`. Every time I press RUN button new container is created as expected but it never do the job and I'm never able to verify it.
In return I can `docker run -it <img> /bin/bash` and `$python --help` is OK.
In the terminal `docker run minimum/docker-django-mysite python --help` is good as well.

This is my debug result:

```
ad0418d30d5a:python -u /opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support --save-threading --save-asyncio --client 10.0.2.2 --port 19383 --file C:/Users/Passanova/PycharmProjects/djangotestone/manage.py runserver 8000

Process finished with exit code 128
```

I even try to change the image whit Django:latest - no effect.

I'm not sure what the `-u` option means but I noticed it is not presented when RUNing with local interpreter.
There is one more thing. It looks like after modifying the pats I escaped most of the path errors. However under Python Console I still have:

```
Error:{"message":"The working directory 'C:/Users/Passanova/PycharmProjects/djangotestone' is invalid. It needs to be an absolute path"}
```

Any help appriciated

Answer (score 0):

it seems like PyCharm is complaining that once inside the Docker instance, the directory C:/Users/Passanova/PycharmProjects/djangotestone doesn't exist -- it only exists on your host machine.

you can run 'docker exec' to run a shell into that docker instance and see what the absolute path would be to the manage.py script. for example, i have a docker instance running redis and i can see that the top-level directory where all files would be is '/data' in my case:

```
[root@ip-10-0-1-1 ~]# docker exec -it sentry_redis_1 /bin/sh
/data # pwd
/data
/data # ls
dump.rdb
```

if you 'docker exec' into your running and instance, you should be able to find your manage.py script and then be able to figure out the absolute path to it from your *container's* point of view. HTH